# RenderMode works when at top of page but not in component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an InputFile for uploading a file on blazor server. If I specify the RenderMode at the top of the page, the `OnChange` command for the InputFile component works, but if it is it the child component then the `OnChange` for the InputFile does not work. Why is this?

This works:

```
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<InputFile id="input-file" OnChange="@LoadFiles" multiple/> 

<label>
    @FileCount
</label>
@code {
   [Parameter]
   public string FileCount { get; set; } = "0";

   private void LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
   {
      FileCount = e.FileCount.ToString();
   }
}
```

This does not:

```
@page "/"

<InputFile id="input-file" OnChange="@LoadFiles" multiple @rendermode=RenderMode.InteractiveServer/> 

<label>
    @FileCount
</label>
@code {
   [Parameter]
   public string FileCount { get; set; } = "0";

   private void LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
   {
      FileCount = e.FileCount.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: The page is overriding the behaviour it is SSR.

Answer (score 1):

It just works as expected,applying render mode to child component won't affect parent component's render mode.The parent component would still be in static by default which is not interactive

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#apply-a-render-mode-programatically) related for more details